# Playing FLV videos in JSP/Java EE

Tags: java, jquery, flash, jsp, flv

I want to play flv videos on my website. The video files are not stored on my server but i only have the url of video . The url of video do not end with .flv. So my flv player( jw player) gives error "video not found " . only if the url is ending with .flv then it plays.

How can i play the videos whose path don't end with  .flv ??
I cant download it on my server and the forward because i don't have  much server space.

My site is in java/jsp with struts.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to download it, but you can still pipeline it through your server.  Java's simple networking apis should let you do this.  Although it seems like a bit much simply for a file extension.  Are you running behind apache?  If so - you can use it as a proxy to other sites (and do regex translations of the url).  That might be the easiest way.

Comment: @ andersonbd1 :Thanks for replying. Can u elaborate plz  on your second solution?i am using apace tomcat as my server

Comment: no - not tomcat - apache http server.  http://httpd.apache.org/ with mod_proxy http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at red5 - it's an opebn source java based implementation of Flash media server. The documentation isn't great but it's quite a good product.

http://code.google.com/p/red5/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flvplayer.swf" width="500" height="450" id="FlvPlayer">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="movie" value=flvplayer.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="scale" value="noScale" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="bgcolor" VALUE="#000000" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="file=robotflv" />
    </object>
```